# Poster Presentation with One or Two Affiliations

Tags: publications, conference, affiliation, poster, video-conference

I am preparing a poster presentation for a scientific conference. When I published my work, I was affiliated with institution X. After my publication, I moved to institution Y. Now, I want to put my affiliation on the poster as well as the institution logo. My question is simple. Which institution should I put on the poster, X or Y? Is it allowed to put both of them since this work was published with an affiliation X but now I am at institution Y?
Your answers are appreciated.

Comment: You should maybe put your subject in the tags or question in case it's relevant. We seem to get this genre of question quite a bit, I know in my field (applied math) nobody really cares, you should put your current affiliation so that if someone Googles your name and affiliation they actually find you.

Comment: Thank you! my field is Physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure-ish mathematics, you should put the institution where you are currently.  A simple footnote stating "Thanks to University X where most of this work was done" will give proper acknowledgement (but is not required).

Answer (score 2):

The conference and people viewing your poster will not care.  Ask your supervisor, just in case they care.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the institution where the bulk of the work was done.  Then a simple footnote stating “present affiliation: University Y” will do the trick.